# ReferenceError: Cannot access <Class> before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I Have simple autoloader method that initializes and returns Instance of class using `require()`

Above simple require is some logic requesting info from database and checking if class exists in filesystem.

```
let elementClass = require('./elements/' + element.name).default;
```

Node and ts-node compiles without problem, but when creating instance by require i get
`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Object' before initialization`

`Object` is main abstract class being extended by `Element` which is then extended by element type.

Required is last in chain class `elementType`

Class is initialized without problem if there is no `Object` class being extended, but `Object` class was tested without any modifications and blank constructor. And all logic transfered to `Element` class

Object.ts

```
export default class Object
{
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public type: string;
    public parent: number;
    public owner: number;
    public permission: string;
    public data: {[name: string]: any};
    protected dataSchema: {[name: string]: any} = {};

    constructor(id: number, name: string, type: string, parent: number, owner: number, permission: string, data: {[name: string]: any})
    {
        if(new Validator().validate(data, this.dataSchema))
            throw new Error('Invalid input data');

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.permission = permission;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Element.ts

```
import Object from "./object";

export default class Element extends Object
{
/**
 * simple logic no constructor
 */
}
```

ElementType.ts

```
import Element from '../element';

export default class ElementType extends Element
{
/**
 * Simple logic without constructor
 */
}
```

Even without any simple methods inside classes it doesn't work, it only works when Main Parent class is not used (`Object`)

Is there some problem requiring class that is twice extended?

Comment: Isn't `Object` a reserved word?

Comment: Now, I feel really stupid, I've looked up everything but this just didn't sparkle to me. Thank you. And sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

Object is reserved word, I just had to rename class to something else.